# PHP/XML - checking if a node is set

Tags: php, xml

I have an XML document structured like this:

```
<produkter>
    <produkt>
        <forhandler></forhandler>
        <produktnavn></produktnavn>
        and so on...
    </produkt>
</produkter>
```

I am pulling out data like this:

```
$produktnavn = utf8_decode($xmlObject->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('produktnavn')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue);
```

Now I am looking to do a check to see if the node is present in the XML document at all.

For example... I only want to make the operation above if there actually IS a node called "produktnavn".

I am trying with:

```
if (isset($xmlObject->item($i)->forhandler)) {
```

But this doesn't seem to work.

What an I doing wrong?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "Doesn't seem to work". What do you expect to see and what do you see instead?

Comment: Unrelated tip/question: is your requirement definitely to convert the text into ISO 8859-1 encoding? If not, [utf8_decode](http://php.net/utf8_decode) is not the function you want. Apologies if you already understand this, but I have seen a lot of misuse of that function as some kind of magic "make my Unicode better", which it is not.

Comment: if (isset($xmlObject->item($i)->forhandler)) {
    $forhandler = utf8_decode($xmlObject->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('forhandler')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue);
} else {
 $forhandler = "Unknown";
}

When I am printing $forhandler it says "Unknown".

Comment: IMSoP : Yes, I am using Scandinavian characters and need to convert into ISO 8859-1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of [`getElementsByTagName`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php) is always a [`DOMNodeList`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php); that class has a member `length`, described as:

> The number of nodes in the list. The range of valid child node indices is 0 to length - 1 inclusive.

So to check if there is at least one item in the list, check that `length` is `> 0`:

```
$produktnavn_nodes = $xmlObject->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('produktnavn');
if ( $produktnavn_nodes->length > 0 ) {
    $produktnavn = utf8_decode($produktnavn_nodes->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue);
    // ... do something with $produktnavn
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) with  [DOMXPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) and check the length for the xpath expression.

For example:

```
$source = <<<SOURCE
<produkter>
    <produkt>
        <forhandler></forhandler>
        <produktnavn></produktnavn>
    </produkt>
</produkter>
SOURCE;

$xmlObject = new DOMDocument;
$xmlObject->loadXML($source);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($xmlObject);
$elements = $xpath->query('//produktnavn');
if ($elements->length > 0) {
    // present
}
```